What's the difference between "enter the door" and "enter at the door"?

He entered the door.

vs.

He entered at the door.

What's the difference between "enter the door" and "enter at the door"?

This needs context.  Neither is particularly likely to be used.

A literal-minded person would say that He entered the door means that he went inside the actual door, rather than entering a room through the doorway!

Do you have any context?
"entered at the door" sounds like "at the door" is simply a qualifier for "entered".
"entered the door" is a bit weird. If it means anything it means they went into the doorway (and maybe stayed there, but that's not obvious).
"entered through the door" would be more usual, but all this depends on what you want to say.

Or "entered via the door" as opposed to entering through the window or some other access point.

Or more usual to use a verb like come or go: "he came/went in the door", etc.

@Stuart. Even in that context I would still say you need something like "he came/went in through the door". You normally enter an area not a door, but the same applies to "coming/going in[to]"

Let's consider these as imperatives:

'Enter the door' is an instruction to go in the door.

'Enter at the door' contains a preposition, so it is an instruction of how to enter into something else that is tacitly understood by the audience (ie it could be taken as "enter the house by the door". If that doesn't make sense, consider the sentence "you should go home" versus "you should go home by bus". The first is telling someone they should leave; the second is telling them how they should leave.


So in your examples, "he entered the door" describes the moment he walked through the doorway; whereas "he entered by the door" tells us how he entered (as opposed to climbing in through the window, perhaps?)
